# GetJsonObject from a for looped JsonArray show syntax error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, for-loop, json

```
     JsonObject jObj = JsonObject.Parse(json);
     JsonArray jArr = jObj.GetNamedArray("records");
     for (int i = 0; i < jArr.Count; i++)
     {
        JsonObject innerObj = jArr.GetObjectAt(i);
        mData[i] = new Data(innerObj .GetNamedString("countryName"), innerObj .GetNamedString("countryId"), innerObj.GetNamedString("callPrefix"), innerObj .GetNamedString("isoCode"));
     }
```

Visual studio show syntax error:
the best overloaded method for jArr.GetObjectAt(uint) has an invalid argument

Comment: Which namespace are you importing `JsonObject` from? (Is this a WP8 Silverlight app, or a Win RT app?)

Comment: @JonSkeet am actually designing for window phone. **using Windows.Data.Json**

Comment: Isn't this because you're trying to use int i, where should be uint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as it states in [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/windows.data.json.jsonarray.getobjectat), you should use uint index, so:

```
JsonObject jObj = JsonObject.Parse(json);
JsonArray jArr = jObj.GetNamedArray("records");
for (uint i = 0; i < jArr.Count; i++)
{
   JsonObject innerObj = jArr.GetObjectAt(i);
   mData[i] = new Data(innerObj .GetNamedString("countryName"), innerObj .GetNamedString("countryId"), innerObj.GetNamedString("callPrefix"), innerObj .GetNamedString("isoCode"));
}
```

should compile.